# Can't rename class in Flutter plugin

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-plugin

I created a new **Flutter plugin** project, **Android Studio** has generated a stub code for me.

Generated classes were called `Accountmanager` and `AccountmanagerPlugin`... Of course, I couldn't agree with these names and renamed it to `AccountManager` and `AccountManagerPlugin` in a whole project where I could find only. I also renamed a method channel from `accountmanager` to `accountManager`.

But now on build I get the error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
e: /Projects/account_manager/android/src/main/kotlin/com/contedevel/accountmanager/AccountManagerPlugin.kt: (12, 14): Redeclaration: AccountManagerPlugin
e: /Projects/account_manager/android/src/main/kotlin/com/contedevel/accountmanager/AccountmanagerPlugin.kt: (12, 14): Redeclaration: AccountManagerPlugin

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

How to fix it?

Link to repo: https://github.com/ConteDevel/flutter-account-manager-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a trivial error... I didn't change a class name in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
flutter:
  plugin:
    androidPackage: com.contedevel.accountmanager
    pluginClass: AccountManagerPlugin # It was `AccountmanagerPlugin`
```

After I rebuilt the project (a simple build didn't help, seems studio cached that file) and it launched.